# Clicking 1 button activates both drop downs

Tags: jquery, html, sass

When I click one of the dropdown buttons it activates both of the dropdowns. I am trying to make it so that when you click one of the dropdown buttons it only activates its specific dropdown. I thought that using the .each() function in jQuery would fix it, but I am most likely using it wrong. Thank you all for your help!

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ianmtrent/zhvgj4ds/) link to the problem

HTML

```html
<div class="mobile-menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>Item 1</a>
        <div class="drop">
          Click To Drop
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a>Sub-item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Sub-item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Sub-item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Sub-item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Sub-item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Item2</a>
        <div class="drop">
          Click To Drop
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a>Sub-item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

SCSS

```css
.drop {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-menu {
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;

        li {
            padding-bottom: 25px;
            position: relative;

            a {
                font-size: rem-calc(30px);
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .nav-dropdown {
                position: relative;
                box-shadow: none;
                background: none;
                height: 100%;
                display: none;
                width: unset;

                li {
                    float: none;
                    max-width: unset;

                    a {
                        font-size: rem-calc(20px);
                        font-weight: normal;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

.nav-dropdown-active {
    display: block !important;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.drop').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      $('.mobile-menu .nav-dropdown').toggleClass('nav-dropdown-active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is:** by using `$('.mobile-menu .nav-dropdown')` you select all the `nav-dropdown` in the `mobile-menu` element .. So you need to use `$(this)` to refer to the clicked `drop` then [**`.next()`**](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the next `ul.nav-dropdown`

- `$(this).next('.nav-dropdown')` OR `$(this).closest('li').find('ul')`
- Also No need to use `.each()`

---

```
$('.drop').click(function() {
   $(this).next('.nav-dropdown').toggleClass('nav-dropdown-active');
});
```

**AND** To close other `nav-dropdown` you can simply use `$('.nav-dropdown').removeClass('nav-dropdown-active');`

```
$('.drop').click(function() {
   $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).next('.nav-dropdown')).removeClass('nav-dropdown-active');
   $(this).next('.nav-dropdown').toggleClass('nav-dropdown-active');
});
```

- By using `.not($(this).next('.nav-dropdown'))` will prevent the desired dropdown to remove class with other dropdown .. this part will help if you have `transition` or `animation` with your active class

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way for it to close the previous one if you open the second one so that there is only one dropdown open at a time?

Comment: @ianmtrent you need to remove the class from other dropdown lists .. answer updated

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're totally welcome @ianmtrent ..Have a great day :-)